# Select top 3 by Take() in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this table

```
EMPs(EmpNo int primary key identity(001,1),
Ename nvarchar(50),
Job nvarchar(20),
Mgr int,
HireDate datetime,
Sal int,
Comm int,
DeptNo)
```

I want to select top 3 who is HiSal?

```
(from a in EMPs
 group a by true into r
 select r.OrderByDescending(x => x.Sall +(x.Comm != null ? x.Comm :0))).Take(3)
```

Comment: What does HiSal mean? What is x.Sall? What is x.Comm? We need more context to this question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're ordering by greatest (salary + commission) to least, then trying to select the top 3.

I think you're making it more complicated than you have to. Try this:

```
var top3salaries = EMPs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Sal + x.Comm).Take(3);
```

Your query also makes it appear that commission can be `null`. If that's the case:

```
var top3salaries = EMPs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Sal + (x.Comm ?? 0)).Take(3);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this query:

```sql
select top(3) EName, MAX(salary) as Hisal
from EMPLOYEES
group by EMPLOYEE_ID
order by MAX(salary) desc
```

Comment: As per your question This query helps you to get top3 highest salary

Comment: The OP clearly wants to use LINQ, not directly write an SQL statement.